# c# Application to create Unity Package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to make a Windows Desktop App in c#, that a user can drag and drop files (models, textures, materials) onto, which then bundles these assets into a Unity Package.

Can this be done from outside Unity using .Net, or can it only be done with Unity's own editor? If so, what NuGet package would be used as there are many Unity packages?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you wouldn't need an app for this.

Unitpackages can afaik only be created using Unity.

Unity has [Command Line Arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) which allow you to export packages via a cmd call afaik like e.g.

```
C:Path\To\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -nographics -projectPath "C:Path\To\A\Unity\Project" -exportPackage "Assets" "C:Path\To\Export\File.unitypackage"
```

Comment: Thanks. So if the assets were copied into the directories of an existing Unity project and this was done in the command line it would then build the package including those assets?

Comment: Thanks. This would rely on the user having Unity installed. Is it possible to just include any NuGet packages in my Windows app so a package could be built regardless of whether the end user has Unity installed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want that, but you can simply put the files you want into a folder as you wish and then convert to a zip file for easy transport internet if that is what you wish. I dont see the point in making a Unity Package for that.

Comment: The user may not have Unity installed or understand how to add assets to Unity, hence a Windows app to do that for them, if this is indeed possible with a NuGet package? So that then anyone who wants to use those assets in their own Unity project can just double click the package and import them.